# Login-AzureRmAccount and Select-AzureRmSubscription

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have installed AzureRm and Azure module on Windows server 2012 R2. I can run other cmdlets from this module (eg.AddAzureRmAccount, Get-AzureRmSubscription) but Login-AzureRmAccount and Select-AzureRmSubscription are throwing not recognized error:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Login-AzureRmAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have already tried uninstalling-reinstalling and  restarting the VM.

What am I doing wrong here? If anyone has solved this before, please suggest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like their powergallery setup is broken, I installed it using webPI and it is working fine.

For webPI download instructions:

https://regularitguy.com/2014/03/13/installing-the-windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets/

Comment: I ended up using the installer hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases referenced from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azureps-cmdlets-docs/

Answer (score 1):

- Install Azure Powershell using latest version of Web Platform
  Installer.
- You may need to restart your machine - so that the latest
  upgrades of powershell will come into effect.
- Open Powershell or Powershell_ise and try executing the below command:

> Login-AzureRmAccount

- A pop-up window comes up prompting your microsoft azure account credentials.

> Install-Module AzureRM -Scope CurrentUser

- Also check your azure installed modules using the below command.

> Get-Module -List

- You are done with setup. Go with your Azure powershell Scripting.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Please use `azure RM` login to connect via service principal as :

```
$applicationId = "$securePassword = "ServicePrincipal Passowrd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "ServicePrincipal Tenant ID"
```