# Select-AzureRMSubscription not recognized

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops

Trying to set up my VSTS windows build agent to accommodate for powershell steps within VSTS but having some problems. Initially it reported that the AzurePS system capability was not present, so I made sure to install the latest Azure modules via the powershell gallery. Now, the AzurePS capability is present but certain powershell commands do not seem to work.

This may not be related to VSTS at all but rather just a configuration issue with my specific powershell installation / configuration. The full error is as follows:

> The term 'Select-AzureRMSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

This error can be seen both in the VSTS release logs of the particular definition I am trying to execute, as well as when attempting to run the Select-AzureRMSubscription command directly on the box itself.

Comment: With azure powershell step/task, you don't need to call Select-AzureRMSubscription manually. Does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 8):

According to [This MS Docs for Get-AzSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azsubscription?view=azps-2.8.0) it's located in the module Az.Accounts.

So I had to run:

```
Install-module Az -AllowClobber -Force
Import-module Az
```

to make the command avaliable to me.

Comment: This helped me... took about 5 min but did the trick

Answer (score 1):

For me, updating the AzureRM module did the trick:

```
Update-Module -Name AzureRM
```

Depending on your system, you may get some messages while installing

> Powershell requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to
>   interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet provider must be
>   available in  'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'
>   or
>   'C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. 
>   You can also install the NuGet provider by running
>   Install-PackagePovider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'.
>   Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import the NuGet provider
>   now?
>
> [Yes] {No] [Suspend]

Choose "Yes"

> You are installling the modules form an untrusted repository. If you
>   trust this repository, change its installationPolicy value by running
>   the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the
>   modules from 'PSGallery'?
>
> [Yes] [Yes to All] [No] [No to All] [Suspend]

Choose "Yes to all"
Up to three modules will be installed/updated and directly after that, the Select-AzureRmSubscription should work immediately.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription b0cabaca-1234-1337-abcd-bebedada1337

# note: this subscription GUID is completely fictional.
# To get the correct one, query your subscriptions with
# Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that certain Azure Powershell modules are installed for certain cmdlets to work. You can check which modules are available by running Get-Module -ListAvailable. Select-AzureRMSubscription requires AzureRM module.
You could just install Azure Powershell with its modules using [webPI](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) - I've never had problems using it and I've heard that installing PS modules using gallery could cause problems (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050880/login-azurermaccount-and-select-azurermsubscription)).

Comment: Thanks for this. The AzureRM module is definitely installed, although I hear what you're saying about using the gallery to install being a problem. Unfortunately though I can't seem to use webpi as it senses Powershell 3.6.0 is installed already and the install box is greyed out. Any way around this?

Comment: install-module azurerm -MinimumVersion 3.6.0

Comment: I can't - the OS in question is server 2012 and it comes pre installed with seemingly no way to remove it

Answer (score 0):

You can run azure PowerShell with [Azure PowerShell step/task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/azure-powershell).

1. Edit your build definition
2. Click Add build step
3. Select Deploy catalog > Add Azure PowerShell step/task

Answer (score 0):

> the OS in question is server 2012

To install PowerShell on windows server 2012, we should add **the .NET Framework 3.5 feature** and add **the windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine** feature.

[image]

About how to add features, refer to the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-the-windows-powershell-2.0-engine?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#on-windows-server-2012-r2-and-windows-server-2012).

Then we can download [PowerShell installation package](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v3.6.0-February2017/azure-powershell.3.6.0.msi), and install it.

Then we can use windows server 2012 PowerShell to login azure.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **`Set-AzContext,`**

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'SubName' | Set-AzContext
```